# Pass the content of a variable instead of variable name

Tags: python

I have this code

```
response = sf.list_state_machines(maxResults=2)
```

I want to:

- make list_state_machines as a passed in argument to the function - named action_cmd
- make maxResults=2 be a passed in argument to the function - named payload
  then I can do the following

`response = sf.action_cmd(payload)`

this does not work, of course. How do I pass these variables so sf recognizes contents of action_cmd as the name of the command and passes the contents of payload as input to the function?

I have no control over the function I am calling

Comment: variables do not *refer to source code*. Variables refer to *objects*. It isn't really clear how you expect this to work. If you could give a clear example, we can help you with alternatives

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you looking for `response = getattr(sf, action_cmd)(**payload)`? where `action_cmd = 'list_state_machines'` and `payload = dict(maxResults=2)`. Or maybe you want `response = action_cmd(**payload)` where `action_cmd = sf.list_state_machines`. There are existing questions about these, like [How to access object attribute given string](/q/2612610/4518341), [Converting dict to kwargs?](/q/5710391/4518341), and [How do I pass a method as a parameter](/q/706721/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better to use a wrapper function,I will give you an example, in my example `action_cmd` is a wrapper function that takes the command and payload as arguments

check this out :

```
def action_cmd(command, **kwargs):
    if command == "list_state_machines":
        return sf.list_state_machines(**kwargs)
    #add your conditions for other commands

#you can use it like this
command = "list_state_machines"
payload = {"maxResults": 2}
response = action_cmd(command, **payload)
```

Comment: Thank you - what you have is what I have now - I am trying to make a generic wrapper where  I can pass in the command and the payload.  I see, now, the command can only be passed in as an item to send me to the correct wrapper.

I wanted to avoid hard-coding the parameters so that a calling program could build the payload as "maxresults=2" and my wrapper would just pass that in to list_state_machines